# GZipping files with python

Tags: python, gzip

Is it normal that gzip algorithm can make file size large after compression? 
E.g. it's needed to split a large file of 8.2Mb into small 101024 chunks of 81 bytes and compress them using gzip library. After it's done I see that folder with gzipped files has become larger in size and it is 13Mb now in comparison with total chunks size without compression. And for example there is a piece of code here:

```
def gzip_it(filenumber, chunk, path=FOLDER_PATH, prefix=FILE_NAME_PREFIX):
    with gzip.open(os.path.join(path, prefix + "{:07d}".format(filenumber) + ".gz"), mode="wb") as chunk_file:
        chunk_file.write(gzip.compress(chunk))

def split_and_write(file, thread_num):
    spare_to_distribute_inner = SPARE_TO_DISTRIBUTE
    initial_position = 0 if thread_num == 0 else BYTES_PER_THREAD * thread_num
    initial_file_num = 0 if thread_num == 0 else FILES_PER_THREAD * thread_num
    with open(file, mode="rb") as file:
         file.seek(initial_position)
         while initial_file_num < FILES_PER_THREAD * (thread_num + 1):
            if spare_to_distribute_inner:
                chunk = file.read(CHUNK_FILE_SIZE + 1)
                gzip_it(initial_file_num, chunk)
                initial_file_num += 1
                initial_position += (CHUNK_FILE_SIZE + 1)
                spare_to_distribute_inner -= 1
            else:
                if initial_file_num == FILES_TOTAL - 1:
                    chunk = file.read(CHUNK_FILE_SIZE + SPARE_TO_DISTRIBUTE_REMAINDER)
                    gzip_it(initial_file_num, chunk)
                    make_marker_file(str(SOURCE_FILE_SIZE).encode())
                    break
                else:
                    chunk = file.read(CHUNK_FILE_SIZE)
                    gzip_it(initial_file_num, chunk)
                    initial_file_num += 1
                    initial_position += CHUNK_FILE_SIZE


def main():
    for thread in range(VIRTUAL_THREADS):
        pool.submit(split_and_write, "cry_cmake.exe", thread)
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is completely normal that files become larger after compression. This happens usually with files that are already compressed.

What you are doing is wrong. Your chunks are too small to be compressed meaningfully. Try making chunks of 1MiB or more.

Basically in a compression, the algorithm looks for repeated sequences and shortens them, creating an initial dictionary with the original sequence and the shortened version.

If the chunks are so small, it can't really find long repeated sequences and it needs to repeat this initial dictionary per every chunk.

Answer (score -1):

How come you want to split the original file first and compress each minichunk by itself?  In most use cases people compress first and split afterwards.

An alternative for your case can be to split the original file into the minichunks but do not compress each of it separately but instead put all of them in one directory and then make a `.tgz` out of the directory:

`tar -c -z -f result.tgz chunks_directory/`

Then the compression takes place after `tar` has bundled all the files again but after unpacking, you will receive all the minichunk files again.